# How to resize popup window from the main page after opening it?

Tags: javascript, dom, popup

I have opened a poup up window with a specific width,height ,top,left.

```
var newwindow=window.open("one.html",'name','height=200,width=650,top=300,left=100');
```

After 5 seconds i need to change the  width,height,top,left of the popup window from a setInterval function in the main page. how can i do that.?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This code must be in child window

```
function calledOnBodyLoad(){
  setTimeout(resize_now, 6000);
}

function resize_now(){
    window.moveTo(new_posx,new_posxy);
    window.resizeTo(newSizeX, newSizeY);
}
```

If you want to control the pop up window from the parent window then use the following (in parent window)

```
////
var newwindow=window.open("one.html",'name','height=200,width=650,top=300,left=100');
setTimeout(resize_now, 6000);
///


 function resize_now(){
        newwindow.moveTo(new_posx,new_posxy);
        newwindow.resizeTo(newSizeX, newSizeY);
    }
```

Remember in this case `newwindow` must be a global variable or pass it as a arguement to the `resize_now` function.

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/MHTnE/2/)

Comment: Don't pass strings to setTimeout, pass functions. `eval` (which you use by proxy if you pass strings) breaks scope, is slow, and makes debugging much harder.

Comment: what it will move.. i nedd to move newly opended pop up window

Comment: yes this will move the pop up window if this code is present there. If you want to control it from parent window you will have to use the `newwindow` variable you mentionedin your question

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `OnLoad` function of `one.html`, add a timer function that will get executed after five seconds. Make the necessary changes in that function.

Comment: i want add the script in the current page and control the opened window.. is it possible?