# How to use resizeBy() on pop-up window in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, resize

I created a "help.html" page, hosted locally, that I open with window.open() as a pop-up. However, when trying to use resizeBy(), nothing changes.
The browser I'm using is Opera GX.

This is the code I used:

```
<button onclick="visitar()">Abrir</button>
<button onclick="dimension()">Redimensionar</button>

<script>
var ventana;
function visitar(){
    ventana = window.open("help.html", "_blank", "width=500, height=300");
};

function dimension(){
    ventana.resizeBy(250, 250);
};
</script>
```

I also tried leaving the page location blank, which does work, but isn't what I need:

```
ventana = window.open("", "_blank", "width=500, height=300");
```

This is the first question I post on here. If you need more details, please tell me.
Thank you in advance!

EDIT (2022.11.9):
Console returns the following message:

> Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from
> accessing a cross-origin frame.
> at dimension (file:///C:/Users/R/Documents/CODE/Javascript4/index.html:20:13)
> at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (file:///C:/Users/R/Documents/CODE/Javascript4/index.html:10:32)

Comment: Not sure if Opera locked down resizing. Are there any errors in your developer console? I would add a type to your button `<button type="button"` to make sure it is not submitting a form.

Comment: @epascarello Thank you, edited the post with the console message. Not sure what it means. Also, adding `type="button"` doesn't seem to solve it.

Comment: Seems like the below [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7036924/10458040) will help you [How to resize popup window from the main page after opening it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7036877/10458040)

Comment: File protocol is useless for development since it is locked down. Run a local server.

Comment: @Basil That seems to work although it's not exactly what I needed. Still, thank you, I learnt something new!

Comment: @epascarello Thank you, it seems that was the issue. I'm still a beginner, so I have difficulty with some terms, but running it through xampp worked.

Answer (score 0):

I made this working using a different API.

Made use of [resizeTo()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resizeTo) instead of [resizeBy()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resizeBy)

Code:

```
<button onclick="opener()">Open</button>
<button onclick="resizer()">Resize</button>

<script>
  var winObj;

  function opener() {
    winObj = window.open("", "_blank", "width=500, height=300");
  };

  function resizer() {
    winObj.resizeTo(500, 500);
  };
</script>
```

Attaching a working demo for better understanding:

[Resize newly opened window](https://jsfiddle.net/basilmohammed/50183v2t/11/)